# Centralizing pm2 logs with elastic search/kibana/logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, elastic-stack, pm2

I was wondering if there was a way to centralize pm2 logs by either sending them to elastic search or integrating pm2 with the ELK stack in some way.

Comment: could you post your configuration or way of solving this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a pm2 module which would send logs to logstash using PM2's `pm2.launchBus(errback)` api (http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/).

As you can see here https://github.com/cliv/pm2-gelf/blob/master/app.js#L24 It's pretty straight forward. The module listens pm2's log events and sends logs using gelf protocol in this case.

Comment: I actually solved this by having logstash listen to the file in which my logs were going to. Thanks for the answer though!